# Await function on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, async-await, onclick

```
async function init() {
  $("#present").slideDown(100);
  setTimeout(btnClose, 4000);
  function btnClose(){ 
    $("#present").slideUp(100);
  }
  $("#present").click(async function() {
    await timerOn();
  });
  moveFunction();
}
```

My `init` function is invoked on a button click... after that a new button appears on screen.... i want to call `timerOn` function but on a button click... now note one thing i have added 'async' in `onClick` because it gives an error that await can be used only in async function....

My purpose is `moveFunction` should be called only after `timerOn` is executed completely...

Will it serve the purpose?? plzzz help...

Comment: You should move `moveFunction();` into click handler after `await timerOn();`

Comment: You should add the code for `timerOn` to your question too.

Comment: @Eldar I thought it will work but it's not working.

Comment: @Andy My timerOn function consists of setInterval where a button appears which invokes another function

Answer (score 1):

Since the buttons will be generated dynamically then the scripts will be unaware of the recently created DOM elements, so you will have to delegate the event to the button  like the following (assuming you are using a class `.present` on your buttons):

```js
 
$( "body" ).delegate( "button.present", "click", function() {
  //do your stuff here
});
```

Comment: I am actually a novice and I am not aware of the delegate function but I read the jquery documentation and tried to understand. I understood a bit but I have no idea how exactly am going to use it in my code. It'll be of great help if you explain it to me in simpler words. Thanking you in advance!

Comment: We use a delegate to attach a handler to one or more events for all the elements that match the selector (for e.g `"button.present"`) whether the elements are already present in the DOM or will be added in the future. You can replace your `click` event with the above one. Where I mentioned `do your stuff here`, you can call your method `timerOn();`

Comment: @RG1nine I know it's a bit confusing, but do go through the following fiddle, [Simple event delegation example](https://jsfiddle.net/founddrama/ggMUn/)

If this is not what you are looking for, then do send mock your scenario in a new [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/), we will help you there. Thanks in advance.